# Azure Blob Storage Sas Generation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, blob, image-uploading

Im a newbie developer. Ive been looking for a newb friendly tutorial on how to generate SAS for azure using javascript. Any help is much appreciated. Please point in the right direction. Thanks, for additional info please ask in the comment section.

Comment: Are you looking for examples of generating SAS using JavaScript or consuming SAS using JavaScript?

Comment: @GauravMantri im looking for examples of generation SAS using javascript

Comment: My recommendation would be to NOT generate SAS using JavaScript. You would need account key to generate SAS and because JavaScript is run on the client browser, your account key is exposed which is not a good thing.

Comment: what would be the required information for the recipe to generate SAS?

Comment: Recommended would be to generate SAS using any of the client libraries on the server side and then use that in your web application.